# Rolling Mean (Altair) is too small

Tags: python, altair, streamlit

On my graph, the rolling mean displayed is too short/small. Is there a way to getting it to go to all the points?

I tried playing around with the frame but it didn't work. Here's the graph I obtain:

[image]

Here's my code :

```
graph =  alt.Chart(df,title=title).mark_point().encode(
                            x=column_x + ":T",
                            y= column_y + ":Q",
                            tooltip=['P_count']
                            ).properties(width=1000,height=500)

line = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(
    color='red',
    size=3
).transform_window(
    rolling_mean="mean("+column_y+")"
).encode(
    x=column_x + ":T",
    y='rolling_mean:Q'
)

text = graph.mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=25
).encode(
    text='P_count'
)

st.altair_chart(graph.interactive() + line + text,  use_container_width=True)
```

Comment: Please include sample data and follow the advice in [mre] to make it easier for contributors on the site to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
.transform_window(
        rolling_mean="mean("+column_y+")",
        frame=[0, 15]
```

I played around with the frame and it worked :)